# how to run a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I made a simple bash script to take the positional parameter direct with the execution like:

```
$ Test $1 $2
```

However, it will not run unless I add `sh` in front of it like
`$ sh Test $1 $2`

I made other scripts with input after being executed and they all run fine without the `sh` in front as I have it in the environment.

My simple program is like

```
echo "my name is $1 I am $2 old."
```

Any idea how i can run it without the `sh` in front?

Comment: Add a shebang and make script executable.

Comment: You avoid `Test` for your script name not to be confused with the `test` builtin.

Answer (score 3):

`Test` needs to be executable

```
chmod +x Test
```

It also needs to be in a directory that's in your `PATH`. If it isn't, you need to be specific:

```
./Test "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: it is executable and it is also in the path. my other scripts are working fine and they take input only after i executed the script then added the variables.
i wanted to execute the script and variables in one line.

Answer (score 2):

In source, you need the path shell

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "my name is $1 I am $2 old."
```

after you set the permission, can you execute

```
$ chmod +x Test
$ ./Test $1 $2
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers given so far is likely to be correct.  But you didn't provide us with enough information to be sure (What O/S are you running?  What -- if any -- response do you get when you run the script?), so here is how you can diagnose the problem yourself.

1)  Enter the command

```
which Test
```

If the `which` command is not installed, skip ahead.  If the answer is

```
/directory/containing/your/script/Test
```

then you know you are actually running your script.  Other possibilities are

- `which: no Test in [list of all directories on your path]`  This means the Test command is simply not being found.  I doubt this is the case, since you say it is in the same directory as other scripts that are working.
- `/usr/bin/test`  This means you are running cygwin under Windows, or some similar system where commands are not case sensitive.  As a result, you are running the system test command instead of your Test script.  Best bet:  rename your script.  (You could put your directory in the front of $PATH so that your script is found instead of the system command -- but that's likely to break something else that uses the system test command.)

2) In the absence of the `which` command, look at what response you get when you run

```
Test Joe 22
```

- If there is no response at all, then odds are that you are running the system test command (see above for comments about cygwin, et al.)
- If you get "Test: command not found" then either the script really isn't on your path, or you incorrectly entered the shebang (#!) line mentioned elsewhere.  Note:  having this line is good form, but in many environments it isn't necessary to get your script to run.

If you are still confused, send us

- What operating system you are running under?
- What response do you get when you run the script?

Optionally, but possibly helpful, add

- Your current working directory (`pwd`)
- The directory containing the Test script
- The contents of your PATH variable (`echo $PATH`)